# Set dynamic values when generating setter methods using attr_accessor in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attr-accessor

Is there a better way to set values to setter methods when they are made dynamically using `attr_accessor` method? I need this for setting values for them from another model in rails. I'm trying to do something like below.

```
Model_class.all.each do |mdl|
  attr_accessor(mdl.some_field)
end
```

Then I know that it creates a set of get and setter methods. What I want to do is, when these methods are get created, i want some value to be specified for setter method.Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know what you are asking for, but my intuition says that you are looking for delegate methods - http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: Better than what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessor` has no magic embedded. For each of params passed to it, it basically executes something like (the code is simplified and lacks necessary checks etc):

```
def attr_accessor(*vars)
  vars.each do |var|
    define_method var { instance_variable_get("@#{var}") }
    define_method "#{var}=" { |val| instance_variable_set("@#{var}", val) }
  end
end
```

That said, the `attr_accessor :var1, :var2` DSL simply brings new 4 plain old good ruby methods. For what you are asking, one might take care about defining these methods (or some of them, or none,) themselves. For instance, for cumbersome setting with checks one might do:

```
attr_reader :variable # reader is reader, no magic

def variable=(val) do
  raise ArgumentError, "You must be kidding" if val.nil?
  @variable = val
end
```

The above is called as usual:

```
instance.variable = 42
#⇒ 42
instance.variable = nil
#⇒ ArgumentError: You must be kidding
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible implementation for this:

```
  def attr_accessor(*args)
    args.each do |attribute|
      define_method(attribute.to_sym) { eval("@#{attribute}") }
      define_method((attribute.to_s + '=').to_sym) {|value| eval("@#{attribute} = value") }
    end
  end
```